# что отвечает за явный return в лямбда?

Tags: kotlin

подскажите, пожалуйста, что в лямбда-выражениях отвечает за явный return ? кроме invoke, с ним все ясно.

Comment: последняя строчка

Comment: @Igor точнее последнее выражение

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon хорошо

Comment: По сути вам уже ответили, не понятно при чем тут invoke?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.